# Show multiple next and previous posts

Tags: pagination, previous, next

I've created a portfolio with single posts. When viewing the posts i'd like to show the next  / previous 2 posts (portfolio items).

Currently i'm using the following code but only shows one post:

```
<?php $prevPost = get_previous_post(true);
    if($prevPost) {?>
    <?php $prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID, array(114,114) );}?>
    <?php previous_post_link('%link',"$prevthumbnail <h3>%title</h3>", TRUE ); ?>
```

I want to create the following:

```
[next post] | [next post] | [current post (active state)] | [previous post] | [previous post].
```

Does anyone know how to change this to a working code?

Answer (score 1):

This one is not a good way to do it but it's easy to implement

```
global $post;
$original = $post;
$next = get_next_post(true);
$prev = get_previous_post(true);
$post = $next;
next_post_link();
$post = $original;
next_post_link();
// display current post
previous_post_link();
$post = $prev;
previous_post_link();
$post = $original;
```

To make the code more efficient, you can copy the respective functions from core code in "wp-includes/link-template.php" & then modify them as required

At the most basic level, in `get_adjacent_post`, change `LIMIT 1` to `LIMIT 2` & `$wpdb->get_row` to `$wpdb->get_results`, then all other function which directly/indirectly use this function will be changed accordingly

NOTE: Don't change the core code, instead copy the functions to your theme/plugin, rename them, modify them, then use the new functions to display the links

Answer (score 0):

`get_previous_post()` and `get_next_post()` both use `get_adjacent_post()`. The function determines the next/previous post by inspecting the global $post object. You could alter the `$post` object to achieve your goal:

```
$current_post = $post; // keep a copy of the current post;

$post = get_previous_post(false); 
echo $post->post_title;
$post = get_previous_post(false);
echo $post->post_title;

$post = $current_post;

$post = get_next_post(false); 
echo $post->post_title;
$post = get_next_post(false);
echo $post->post_title;
```

Comment: Thanks @daniel looks like this is what I need.. BUT as I'm not a php programmer (sorry only front end skills), how do I transform this code into echo this:

[code]<a href="get_post_link"><thumb><title><a>[/code]

Answer (score 0):

Had to mix up some stuff, but this is my result:

This can be handy for more people who want to create a portfolio with a strong next/previous system.

Thanks all for the help!

```
<?php
$current_post = $post; // keep a copy of the current post;

$post = get_previous_post(false); 
$attr = array(
                                'title' => $post->post_title,
                                'alt' => $post->post_title,
                                'class' => 'meta_icon'
                            );
echo "<a href='".$post->guid."'>";
echo "<div class='meta_apps'>";
echo "<div class=\"meta-icon\">".get_the_post_thumbnail($post->post_id, 'thumbnail', $attr)."</div>";
echo "<div class=\"meta-title\">".$post->post_title."</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</a>";

$post = get_previous_post(false);
$attr = array(
                                'title' => $post->post_title,
                                'alt' => $post->post_title,
                                'class' => 'meta_icon'
                            );
echo "<a href='".$post->guid."'>";
echo "<div class='meta_apps'>";
echo "<div class=\"meta-icon\">".get_the_post_thumbnail($post->post_id, 'thumbnail', $attr)."</div>";
echo "<div class=\"meta-title\">".$post->post_title."</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</a>";

$post = get_previous_post(false);
$attr = array(
                                'title' => $post->post_title,
                                'alt' => $post->post_title,
                                'class' => 'meta_icon'
                            );
echo "<a href='".$post->guid."'>";
echo "<div class='meta_apps'>";
echo "<div class=\"meta-icon\">".get_the_post_thumbnail($post->post_id, 'thumbnail', $attr)."</div>";
echo "<div class=\"meta-title\">".$post->post_title."</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</a>";

$post = $current_post;
$post = get_next_post(false);

$attr = array(
                                'title' => $post->post_title,
                                'alt' => $post->post_title,
                                'class' => 'meta_icon'
                            );
echo "<a href='".$post->guid."'>";
echo "<div class='meta_apps'>";
echo "<div class=\"meta-icon\">".get_the_post_thumbnail($post->post_id, 'thumbnail', $attr)."</div>";
echo "<div class=\"meta-title\">".$post->post_title."</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</a>";

$post = get_next_post(false);
$attr = array(
                                'title' => $post->post_title,
                                'alt' => $post->post_title,
                                'class' => 'meta_icon'
                            );
echo "<a href='".$post->guid."'>";
echo "<div class='meta_apps'>";
echo "<div class=\"meta-icon\">".get_the_post_thumbnail($post->post_id, 'thumbnail', $attr)."</div>";
echo "<div class=\"meta-title\">".$post->post_title."</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</a>";



// $post = get_next_post(false); 
// echo $post->post_title;
// $post = get_next_post(false);
// echo $post->post_title;

get_post_thumbnail();
next_post_link();
previous_post_link();
?>
```